# How do I prepend a directory the library path when loading a core file in gdb on Linux

Tags: linux, path, gdb, coredump

I have a core file generated on a remote system that I don't have direct access to.  I also have local copies of the library files from the remote system, and the executable file for the crashing program.

I'd like to analyse this core dump in gdb.

For example:

```
gdb path/to/executable path/to/corefile
```

My libraries are in the current directory.

In the past I've seen debuggers implement this by supplying the option "-p ." or "-p /=."; so my question is:

How can I specify that libraries be loaded first from paths relative to my current directory when analysing a corefile in gdb?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Start gdb without specifying the executable or core file, then type the following commands:

```
set solib-absolute-prefix ./usr
file path/to/executable
core-file path/to/corefile
```

You will need to make sure to mirror your library path exactly from the target system.  The above is meant for debugging targets that don't match your host, that is why it's important to replicate your root filesystem structure containing your libraries.

If you are remote debugging a server that is the same architecture and Linux/glibc version as your host, then you can do as [fd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13956/fd) suggested:

```
set solib-search-path <path>
```

If you are trying to override some of the libraries, but not all then you can copy the target library directory structure into a temporary place and use the `solib-absolute-prefix` solution described above.

Comment: I got the path a little wrong, so you may want to update your answer to match.  I'll upvote this answer because it partially fits my requirement, but I should state more clearly I want to prepend a location to the library path rather than replace it (my bad for the use of the word "override").

Comment: In my case the executable and its libraries were in an NFS-mounted tree and the host I wanted to debug from was the NFS server, so I put a symlink in the tree so that solib-absolute-prefix nfs-share-tree was the exact solution. I hope this helps future generations.

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure this is possible at all within gdb but then I'm no expert.

However I can comment on the *Linux* dynamic linker. The following should print the path of all resolved shared libraries and the unresolved ones.

```
ldd path/to/executable
```

We need to know how your shared libraries were linked with your executable. To do this, use the following command:

```
readelf -d path/to/executable | grep RPATH
```

- Should the command print nothing, the dynamic linker will use standard locations plus the LD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable to find the shared libraries.
- If the command prints some lines, the dynamic linker will ignore LD_LIBRARY_PATH and use the hardcoded rpaths instead.

  If the listed rpaths are absolute, the only solution I know is to copy (or symlink) your libraries to the listed locations.

  If the listed rpaths are relative, they will contain a $ORIGIN which will be replaced at run time by the path of the executable. Move either the executable or the libraries to match.

For further informations, you could start with:

```
man ld.so
```

Comment: very useful information . not related to gdb but very related to my case of finding ld paths

Answer (score 4):

I found this excerpt on [developer.apple.com](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/DeveloperTools/gdb/gdb/gdb_16.html)

> ```
> set solib-search-path path
> ```
>
> If this variable is set, path is a
>   colon-separated list of directories to
>   search  for shared libraries.
>   `solib-search-path' is used after`
>   solib-absolute-prefix' fails to
>   locate the library, or if the path to
>   the library is relative instead of
>   absolute. If you want to use
>   `solib-search-path' instead of`
>   solib-absolute-prefix', be sure to
>   set `solib-absolute-prefix' to a
>   nonexistant directory to prevent GDB
>   from finding your host's libraries.

**EDIT:**

I don't think using the above setting prepends the directories I added, but it does seem to append them, so files missing from my current system are picked up in the paths I added.  I guess setting the solib-absolute-prefix to something bogus and adding directories in the solib-search-path in the order I need might be a full solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just set LD_PRELOAD to each of the libraries or LD_LIBRARY_PATH to the current directory when invoking gdb. This will only cause problems if gdb itself tries to use any of the libraries you're preloading.

Comment: Command  LD_LIBRARY_PATH="." gdb executableName.bin   worked fine.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

One important note:

if you're doing a cross compiling and trying to debug with gdb, then
after you've done 
`file ECECUTABLE_NAME` if you see smth. like :

```
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/libthread_db.so.1"
```

then check whether you have libthread_db for your target system. I found a lot of similar problems on the web. Such problem cannot be solved just using "set solib-", you has to build libthread_db using your cross-compiler as well.