# How do I prepend a directory the library path when loading a core file in LLDB on Linux

Tags: gdb, cross-platform, lldb

I have found the same question asking about [how to do this in GDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/84341/how-do-i-prepend-a-directory-the-library-path-when-loading-a-core-file-in-gdb-on) but after a lot of searching I have no idea how to do it in LLDB.

The [solib-absolute-prefix and solib-search-path](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Files.html) are the solution but I don't know what the LLDB equivalent is. Anyone know?